# Fill sin_zero in sockaddr_in in Windows

Tags: windows, assembly

In a x86 stack I needn't fill sin_zero with 2 "push 0" in POSIX-compliant architectures. But must I in Windows?

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

Comment: `sin_zero` in the [sockaddr_in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx63b042.aspx) structure is documented as: *"Padding to make structure the same size as SOCKADDR."* If you want to manually construct a `sockaddr_in` instance on the stack, you must make enough room for it. Whether you use `sub esp,8` or 2 `push 0xbabe2bed` instructions is irrelevant.

Comment: mm I understand. But in Windows, for example, is it obligatory I fill this 8 bytes?

Comment: The structure is defined to have a specific layout. This is true for all platforms. Whether you fill the 8 bytes in `sin_zero` with data, or merely allot space for them, is of no relevance. If you are having trouble translating this into assembly, use a C compiler instead and have it do the math.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think the confusion is the name of this element: It is named "sin_zero" and not "sin_unused" what suggests that it is mandataory to fill this element with zeros - independent of the programming language used.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is recommended to actually zero `sin_zero`.

Officially it is not required by the standard, but some [sources](https://silviocesare.wordpress.com/2007/10/22/setting-sin_zero-to-0-in-struct-sockaddr_in/) claim that not zero-ing can result in undefined behavior on some architectures. Something I also observed in a project myself.

Furthermore, [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in?redirectedfrom=MSDN) documentation mentions the following about `sin_zero`:

> Reserved for system use. A WSK application should set the contents of
>   this array to zero.

More info in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086642/is-zeroing-out-the-sockaddr-in-structure-necessary).