# Is zeroing out the "sockaddr_in" structure necessary?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Everywhere I look, I see the following piece of code:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
```

In C++, the same idea is usually expressed as

```
sockaddr_in addr = {}; // unneccesary(?) value-initialzation
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip;
```

Yet nowhere I look (in terms of official documentation) do I see any requirement to zero out the structure before setting those members! Yes, usually BSD sockets implementations do have a `sin_zero` member defined for `sockaddr_in`, but they always say the member is needed for padding, to align the size of `sockaddr_in` with `sockaddr`. And they never request one to put any specific contents into it.

Is there any **real**, **documentation proven** need to zero out the struct?

P.S.
Before you VTC the question as a duplicate of one of several SO questions regarding `memset` on `sockaddr_in`, please make sure the question your are suggesting as a duplicate has any links to official documentation rather than just speculation on 'initializing of unused members just in case'.

Comment: Note: unbalanced parentheses: `memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr);` -->> `memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);`

Comment: I removed the [tag:language-lawyer] tag since it makes no sense in this context.

Comment: @black, it does make sense, and this is what the question is about. Here is the tag description: "For questions about the intricacies of formal or authoritative specifications of programming languages and **environments**". I am asking for authoritive specification.

Comment: @SergeyA I shall say I was not aware of the 'environment' part. But it is very misleading. Furthermore, all the questions I've seen with such tag were about language formalities: it is, after all, _language_ lawyer, not _environment_ lawyer also because languages are independent from the environment, let alone formal specifications. Guess a Q on meta is worth.

Comment: @black, we do not have 'environment-lawyer', so I've choosen formally matching tag. If you do ask a meta question, I'd love to see the link.

Comment: It is a cargo cult, like casing the return value of `malloc`. There seems to be no formal need to zero the padding. But there are anecdotal reports that failure do to so might lead to bad consequences in APIs that internally reinterpret `sockaddr_in` as `sockaddr`.

Comment: BTW: you dont *need* the extra pair of parentheses. `memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);` is correct, since `addr` is not a typename. (the won't do anay harm exept for the human reader, comparable to the memset() thing, which most probably is cargo-cult)

Comment: They've finally stopped using `bzero`?

Comment: @AnT, I share the same belief. Yet I've seen 200K+ StackOverflow posters (not mentioning any names here! ;) who trully believe it is neccesary. I'd like to have a formal closure on this.

Comment: @joop, that I know. I just love those parenthises, they please me aestethically.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley, well, some of them still do, "they certainly do"  (C).

Comment: They confuse me; I always think they are actually needed, while they are not. Just like the memset(), it is cargocult and defensive programming.

Comment: @joop, nah, they are aestethical thing for me. Like spacing between function name and opening parenthis, space before/after `&` and `*`, same line or next line for `{`. You can use whatever you want in your code, but please don't police other people's code.

Comment: @SergeyA I opened a question on Meta, you may want to check it out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319310/what-are-environments-in-the-language-lawyer-tag). Thanks for bringing up the point.

Comment: About the *// unneccesary(?) value-initialzation* comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069634/613130

Comment: @xanatos, I didn't quite get what you are saying here.

Comment: @SergeyA The comment in the code seems to imply that `sockaddr_in addr = {}` is equivalent to `sockaddr_in addr;`, so that in C++ both will zero all the fields. The link I provided says the opposite, because `sockaddr_in` doesn't have a constructor that initializes the field, so `sockaddr_in addr;` leave its fields with unspecified value.

Comment: @xanatos, no, it doesn't imply that. It implies that the code performs value initialization, which is not necessary. It is equivalent of C memset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer:

The IEEE Standard doesn't require it.

But, I think it's best to be safe and zero out everything.

---

### Long(er) answer:

The [IEEE Standard
1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html) specifies that the definition of `sockaddr_in` is (**Emphasis** mine):

> The <netinet/in.h> header shall define the sockaddr_in structure that
> includes **at least** the following members:
>
> `sa_family_t     sin_family   AF_INET.`
>
> `in_port_t       sin_port    Port number.`
>
> `struct in_addr  sin_addr     IP address.`

Note that, unlike the definition for `sockaddr_in6`, which specifies that it *should* be zeroed out:

> The `sockaddr_in6` structure shall be set to zero by an application
> prior to using it, since implementations are free to have additional,
> implementation-defined fields in `sockaddr_in6`.

There is no similar wording for `sockaddr_in`. However, such lack of wording gives platform implementors enough ambiguity to make their own requirements about zeroing out all or part of `sockaddr_in`.

Note that the definition of `sockaddr_in` [used to](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html) require a `sin_zero` field to pad out the structure to make it compatible with `sockaddr` structures:

> The sin_zero member was removed from the sockaddr_in structure as per
> The Open Group Base Resolution bwg2001-004.

And it's with `sin_zero` we find a discrepancy between Windows and Linux. Even though the field was removed from the official definition, both Windows and Linux implementation still include it (because it's not explicitly illegal thanks to the wording "at least").

Whether `sin_zero` always requires zeroing out or not for Windows platforms isn't clear, but in [this blog post](https://silviocesare.wordpress.com/2007/10/22/setting-sin_zero-to-0-in-struct-sockaddr_in/) the writer did some digging and came up with the following:

> On some architectures, it wont cause any problems not clearing
> sin_zero.  But on other architectures it might.  Its required by
> specification to clear `sin_zero`, so you must do this if you intend
> your code to be bug free for now and in the future.

For the part about "It's required by specification to clear `sin_zero`", I could only find the following [Windows documentation (for Winsock Kernel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570823(v=vs.85).aspx) appearing to support the claim:

> A WSK application should set the contents of this array to zero.

However, I can find no similar wording for Linux.

So to conclude, it appears that in some architectures you need to zero out at least one field, while in others you don't. I think it's best to be safe and zero out everything.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. First, it says moot points about being a non-C/C++ standard (everybody knows that), than it goes into lengthy **incorrect** details about Linux sockaddr_in implementations (it **surely** has a padding member to conform to the size of sockaddr structure) and lastly talks about Windows Kernel Sockets application, of which my question is not.

Comment: The discussion on architecture specific implementations seems relevant because of the non-standardness. Apologies if I got any detail swrong about the linux impl. I dont intend to mislead, and I thought the source was reliable.

Comment: @SergeyA: I did a little more digging and updated the post with what I hope is better sourcing.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not the answer at all. It is a lengthy statement that you don't know the answer.

Comment: @SergeyA: What I understood was that your question was asking for official documentation, and in this post I show that the official documentation makes no requirement. Would you prefer that I remove all the background information (or just show the relevant excerpt from the standard)? I thought the rest was informative, but I could understand an argument against a wall of text.

Comment: just squeeze it a bit. The note about IEEE standard not requiring it is a good one. The mentioning of AF_INET6 zeroing requirements is also a good one (not my question, but a good reference). Remove details on `struct sockaddr`, the question is not about it. Do not repeat yourself. And than it would be an answer worth accepting! :)

Comment: @SergeyA:  I've cut out a large amount of the discussion. Please let me know if I worded anything incorrectly or ambiguously.

Comment: Ok, I do not agree with conclusion (it appears that on **neither** architecture you need to zero the field unless you are writing winsock kernel apps!) but conclusions are left to the readers anyway. I am accepting this answer (and retracting my downvote:)

Comment: @SergeyA: Thank you. You certainly made me work for it, and I appreciate the opportunity to improve!

Comment: As of the 2018 version of the IEEE/Open Group specifications (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) there is now a clarifying (but non-normative) "Application Usage" section, which confirms that for sockaddr_in (as opposed to sockaddr_in6) there is no requirement to zero-init, but that you are "encouraged" to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party - but here's something relevant, that I think is a worthwhile addition to the discussion. In the 3rd edition of the “Unix Network Programming” of Richard Stevens, on page 70, there's this:

*“...when binding non-wildcard IPv4 address, this member must be zero (pp. 731-732 of TCPv2)”*

Stevens here mentions "TCPv2" - and the "member" he is talking about is `sin_zero`. This seems to fit with the profile of your question...  at least in the context of `bind`-ing. Notice that he uses the word **must**.

Whether this answer qualifies for "official documentation" or not... I leave that up to you! But as others have said, regardless of whether it's official or not... it's for sure a good idea to `memset` to zero (or use `= {0};` at structure variable definition). In this way, you have one less thing to worry about...

Comment: Here "TCPv2" refers to Stevens' own book *TCP/IP Illustrated,* volume 2, not to any version 2 of the TCP protocol. And certainly neither of these books is official documentation, although extremely handy of course.